# NodeJs application not connecting to MySql after deployment in IIS 10 using IISNODE

Tags: mysql, node.js, iis

I have build a application using NodeJS, MySQL & express, deployed on IIS 10 on window server machine. when I run this application locally it is working fine. But after deployment NodeJS application not making a connection to the MySQL database. I am not able to figure it out why this is happening.
Does it required any configuration on IIS or web config ?
I have stored the database connection details in .env file and reading it from there.
I have installed odbc MySQL driver in server machine too.

1. Db connection file

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
const mysql2 = require('mysql2');

class DBConnection {
    constructor() {
        this.db = mysql2.createPool({
            host: process.env.DB_HOST,
            user: process.env.DB_USER,
            password: process.env.DB_PASS,
            database: process.env.DB_DATABASE
        });

        this.checkConnection();
    }

    checkConnection() {
        this.db.getConnection((err, connection) => {
            if (err) {
                if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
                    console.error('Database connection was closed.');
                }
                if (err.code === 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR') {
                    console.error('Database has too many connections.');
                }
                if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
                    console.error('Database connection was refused.');
                }
            }
            if (connection) {
                console.log('Database connected successfully')
                connection.release();
            }
            return
        });
    }

    query = async (sql, values) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const callback = (error, result) => {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                    return;
                }
                resolve(result);
            }
            // execute will internally call prepare and query
            this.db.execute(sql, values, callback);
        }).catch(err => {
            const mysqlErrorList = Object.keys(HttpStatusCodes);
            // convert mysql errors which in the mysqlErrorList list to http status code
            err.status = mysqlErrorList.includes(err.code) ? HttpStatusCodes[err.code] : err.status;

            throw err;
        });
    }
}

// like ENUM
const HttpStatusCodes = Object.freeze({
    ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD: 422,
    ER_DUP_ENTRY: 409
});


module.exports = new DBConnection().query;
```

2. My model.js file

```
const query = require('../db/db-connection');
const { multipleColumnSet } = require('../utils/common.utils');

class MainModel {
    tableName = 'ProductTable_status';

    find = async (params = {}) => {
        let {ProductID, country} = params;
        
        let sql = `SELECT * FROM ${this.tableName} WHERE ProductID= ? AND country = ?`;        
        
        return await query(sql, [ProductID, country]);
    }
module.exports = new MainModel;
```

3. Calling the model

```
 let row = await MainModel.find({ProductID: data[i].inputString, country: data[i].country});
```

4. env file

```
# DB Configurations
DB_HOST="######"
DB_USER="#########"
DB_PASS="##########"
DB_DATABASE="##########"
```

what extra steps it required to work on IIS 10 ? It is working file locally.

Did I miss anything here to run this application on IIS 10 ?

Comment: I think it is because of your IIS permissions that it cannot connect to MYSQL. You try to open IIS with administrator permissions and run the application.

Comment: @Theobald Du - Thanks for your reply. can you please elaborate more, I didn't get it. Application is already hosted in IIS 10 windows server. You want me login in server machine and open IIS in administrator mode manually and test the application. Is that what you are saying ? I tried this also but no luck.

Comment: You can try to add IIS permissions to the database: https://support.pkware.com/home/smar/18.2/sem-knowledge-base/kb-granting-folder-permissions-to-iis-application-pools